# Is there a word for love of nightmares/dark/macabre things?

Tags: single-word-requests

Just like there is *nyctophilia* for the love of darkness, I was hoping for a word that can come close to summarizing love of nightmares and dark, macabre things.

Any clues?

Comment: Single word requests  should provide an example sentence about the way the word will be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[morbid](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/morbid)**

*adjective*

- suggesting an unhealthy mental state or attitude; unwholesomely gloomy, sensitive, extreme, etc.:
  *a morbid interest in death.*
- gruesome; grisly.

Comment: I'd suggest tossing in "macabre" as well. (+1, regardless)

Comment: This unfortunately is a "phobia/philia" type of question. However, I think you nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

> **Goth** (noun) **Gothic** (adj.)
>   a style of rock music derived from punk, typically with apocalyptic or mystical lyrics.
>
> **a member of a subculture favouring black clothing, white and black make-up, and goth music**.
>   — Google's dictionary.

[Wikipedia's Goth subculture article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goth_subculture) covers music, fashion, literature and more, e.g.

> **Gothic literature** is a genre of fiction that combines romance and dark elements to produce mystery, suspense, terror, horror and the supernatural

Comment: I think it's safe to say that this is not apposite. Goth/Gothic involves a whole subculture, as pointed out in the definition which you cited. It is much more profound, involving and being based on other things than fondness of morbidness. I think Taxidiotis proposition is more fitting.

Answer (score 1):

**Phobophilia,** which literally translates to "love of fear," from *phobo* meaning fear and *philia* meaning love, would fit in nicely. A person who loves the disturbing and horrifying, then, may be known as a phobophile.

*Exercising his **phobophilia**, Justin decided to help the Exorcist increase its box office take.*